# Inner query or multiple queries which would be result in better performance for mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Inner query:

```
select up.user_id, up.id as utility_pro_id from utility_pro as up
join utility_pro_zip_code as upz ON upz.utility_pro_id = up.id and upz.zip_code_id=1
where up.available_for_survey=1 and up.user_id not in (select bjr.user_id from book_job_request as bjr where 
((1583821800000 between bjr.start_time and bjr.end_time) and (1583825400000 between bjr.start_time and bjr.end_time)))
```

Divided in two queries:

1. `select up.user_id, up.id as utility_pro_id from utility_pro as up
   join utility_pro_zip_code as upz ON upz.utility_pro_id = up.id and upz.zip_code_id=1`
2. `Select bjr.user_id as userId from book_job_request as bjr where bjr.user_id in :userIds and (:startTime between bjr.start_time and bjr.end_time) and (:endTime between bjr.start_time and bjr.end_time)`

*Note*:
*As per my understanding, when single query will be executed using inner query it will scan all the data of book_job_request but while using multiple queries rows with specified user ids will be checked.*

Any other better option for the same operation other than these two is also appreciated.

Comment: You can test this for yourself faster and more accurately than any answer we could provide here but, generally, the fewer round trips to the database, the better.

Comment: "will scan all" -- Depends on whether there is an adequate index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the query is supposed to be more like this:

```
SELECT up.user_id
     , up.id utility_pro_id 
  FROM utility_pro up
  JOIN utility_pro_zip_code upz 
    ON upz.utility_pro_id = up.id
  LEFT
  JOIN book_job_request bjr 
    ON bjr.user_id = up.user_id
   AND bjr.end_time >= 1583821800000
   AND bjr.start_time <= 1583825400000
 WHERE up.available_for_survey = 1 
   AND upz.zip_code_id = 1
   AND bjr.user_id IS NULL
```

For further help with optimisation (i.e. which indexes to provide) we'd need SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the EXPLAIN for the above

Comment: Consider providing the optimal indexes, too.

Comment: Can you explain it more? @RickJames
I ended up with following query:

`select up.user_id from utility_pro as up
join utility_pro_zip_code as upz ON upz.utility_pro_id = up.id and upz.zip_code_id=1
left join book_job_request as bjr ON bjr.user_id = up.user_id and ((1583821800000 between bjr.start_time and bjr.end_time) and (1583825400000 between bjr.start_time and bjr.end_time))
where up.available_for_survey=1 and bjr.user_id is NULL`

Comment: @RickJames I'm not doing that without the requested information. Aside from the fact that I'd probably get it wrong , I think it's reasonable that the OP makes some effort in this regard.

Comment: @HoneyShah - I'll repeat Strawberry's request for `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @Strawberry and RickJames Sorry for the delay posting create table commands.
I have uploaded all required commands over this link:
https://filebin.net/9sjuxmt2vm3ao3mf/create-tables.sql?t=aufcq4wu

Comment: @RickJames I need to filter user_ids from utility_pro table which are working with the same zip code provided as a variable value and the flag available_for_survey should be true. Other than this, there is a table called "book_job_request", which stores the time slot for which user is not available for other service so I am also filtering records whether for provided timeslot user is available or not.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
SELECT  up.user_id , up.id utility_pro_id
    FROM  utility_pro up
    JOIN  utility_pro_zip_code upz  ON upz.utility_pro_id = up.id
    WHERE  up.available_for_survey = 1
      AND  upz.zip_code_id = 1
      AND  bjr.user_id IS NULL
      AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM book_job_request
                           WHERE user_id = up.user_id
                             AND end_time   >= 1583821800000
                             AND start_time <= 1583825400000 )
```

Recommended indexes (for my NOT EXISTS and for Strawberry's LEFT JOIN):

```
book_job_request:  (user_id, start_time, end_time)
upz:  (zip_code_id, utility_pro_id)
up:  (available_for_survey, user_id, id)
```

The column order given is important.  And, no, the single-column indexes you currently have are not as good.